# User Interaction is not storing on MongoDb - Once browser is closed

Tags: experience-analytics, mongodb, session-state

We have a simple Website which has WFFM form, there is no login page. When user is closing browser directly that time interaction is not capturing into MongoDb. Probably session end is not firing.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: If user is idle for longtime then based timeout setting, its pursing interaction to mongo db.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs on your CD to see if there are any issues writing to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closing the browser will not end/expire the session. That is done after user is idle for 30 mins time by default.

But you can adjust that from adjusting "timeout" parameter of the following tag in the web.config file

```
<authentication …> 
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="2" />
</authentication>
```

I have blog about the WFFM data flow process for sc 8 versions in the following links in case you need to get full cycle of the data flow.

https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2015/06/data-flow-sitecore-wffm-part-1.html
https://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.com/2015/07/data-flow-sitecore-webforms-for-2.html

Comment: Tip: For testing purpose you can build a page with a Session.Abandon(); to avoid waiting. see http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-tips-and-tricks-2016/